Novel where the characters can control elements and tournaments are hosted among four kingdoms
I am looking for a novel where the character can control elements. They can control only one or two and the lucky ones can control three, because their power is diminishing, but there is a boy who can control all the elements. They usually host tournaments among all the four kingdoms. The winner of the tournament will be promoted in rank. They also embark on a journey to the lair of the evil lord. There is a fifth kingdom, but it belongs to an evil lord and the people there cultivate evil energy.
I have forgotten many things about the novel but I remember this much.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?
